# Get the current Raspbian kernel version without installing

Tags: raspbian, kernel

Is there a way to get the current version of the kernel for the Raspbian distribution, **without installing it**?

I don't really want only the number, I really would like a procedure to get it next year.

Comment: Why the entire kernel?  Consider what can be done with the command "insmod".  Read about it and, perhaps, re-word your question to make it clearer what you want to do.

Comment: @st2000, thank you for you comment, I have reworded my question. Now it has nothing to do with modules

Comment: @pim Do you want only the source code?

Comment: @tlhIngan, I'm interested in the kernel release number, not the sources

Comment: Ok, so you just want to know the kernel version of the current Raspbian distribution before installing it.  @Millways 's answer should work.  But I'll post a more generic way along with a few other places to look.

Comment: "it" is an indefinite article whose meaning is assumed to refer to definite articles previously mentioned. The "normal" interpretation is the first definite article mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking for a generic way to determine the kernel version with out installing / running the Raspbian image appears a bit of a challenge.  (I'll gladly change this answer if someone comments with a better way.)

If you look at the [Raspbian release notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt), you will see an occasional entry regarding the kernel.  Unfortunately seldom is the kernel version included.

If you look at the [Raspbian wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian), you will find a table of release dates, Debian versions names and kernel versions.  This page spans years of Raspbian distributions and (currently) only lags the available download images by about 3 months.

And (as @Milliways points out) you can download the *.info file for the distribution you are interested in.  Start in this directory:

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/

...then drill down into the release of interest, download the file ending in .info and search for "Linux version".  Here is the entry from the newest Raspbian distribution:

```
Uname string: Linux version 4.9.59-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017
```

Answer (score 3):

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2017-12-01/2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch.info contains details of the "latest", including kernel version.

The parent directories have all versions, so you would have to select the latest.

Comment: Your answer clarified the question... Now I get it.

Comment: I voted up this one, since this is what I'm asking, but is there a way to know if there is a kernel update, like https://packages.debian.org or https://packages.ubuntu.org? And I will accept it in some days if there is no better anwer ;)

Comment: You could do `apt update` and check if `raspberrypi-kernel` is listed - this was not the question you asked.

Comment: still the same thing, how will I apt update without installing?

Comment: `update` **DOES NOT** install anything, merely update the list of installation candidates. This question is a moving target - you should edit additional detail into the question. You haven't even explained what utility there is in knowing the magic number of the latest supported kernel.

Comment: when I say not installing I mean not installing raspbian.

Comment: @pim So **NOW** you appear to be stating you are not using Raspbian, have no intention of installing it, but for some undisclosed reason want to know what kernel version Raspbian uses!!!!!!!  I might add it would be a trivial exercise to write a script (using the information in the answer above) under any OS to find this.

Comment: @Milliways, it seems I have written an unclear question, and I'm sorry about that. I wanted to know which kernel is used by raspbian, before installing raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `Packages` file for the raspbian distribution, for jessie:

```
wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages
```

Get the `raspberrypi-kernel` package version :

```
cat Packages | grep raspberrypi-kernel_
```

Result :

```
Filename: pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/raspberrypi-kernel_1.20170703-1_armhf.deb
```

The interesting part is **`1.20170703-1`**, this number can be found on the Rasperry PI's [kernel page on gitub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/releases/) and search for the this release number. This will show :

```
Merge remote-tracking branch 'stable/linux-4.9.y' into rpi-4.9.y
```

In this case the kernel is 4.9.

Comment: the '1.20170703-1' piece of information can be retrieved as easy like this: 'apt-cache show raspberrypi-kernel-headers'